# NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

What is the equivalent Swift code of the Objective-C code below?

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
```

Comment: Have you found what the Swift code is? I really would need this for testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available on the `Foundation` framework. It's from **Apple** private API and **Apple** says that your application will get rejected if you use private API.

Comment: While true, that is irrelevant since the initial question could pertain to a testing environment on localhost, etc

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION**:

Add this to file info.plist which will force ATS to accept self signed certificate:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/> -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

However, as explain [here](http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/) this is not enough. In each class where you will use NSURLSession you have to declare the following delegate:

```
class LoginService: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    task: NSURLSessionTask,
    didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?)
    -> Void) {

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

...
```

}

And then perform something like the following:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    /*
    dataTaskWithRequest: creates an HTTP request for the specified URL request object, and calls a handler upon completion.
    */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest...)
```

This works for me. Remember that you must use Apache **2.4.x** because it's the only version supporting TLS 1.2.
Hope this will help.

Comment: This is by far the best and most complete description on StackOverflow. Of course you need to understand the risks, and so on. But if you just need to try something out, perfect! Thanks

Regarding the risks:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: you're very kind, thank you. I know the risk but the company I was working for did not want to have a server with ssl certificate because they say it costs too much, is it right?

Comment: Security will always have some overhead in CPU power. I found this nice website about it: https://istlsfastyet.com/
I wonder if the company does any other optimisations possible.

Comment: Ehm, when they say it costs too much they mean that buying or renting a server with a ssl certificate is very money expensive...

Comment: To check target server's TLS parameters do this in Terminal: "openssl s_client  -connect <your host>:<port>" and check the fields for "SSL-Session:..." in the end of the answer.